# (Javascript) How to changed a variable value based on selected option in a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a dropdown list right here and I have declared a variable (vki)

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        Select your favorite letter!
        <select id="Fletter">
            <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
            <option>E</option>
            <option>F</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script>
        var vki,
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want (vki) to have different values when different option is selected. For example, vki=5 when A is selected, vki=7 when B is selected, how would I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object to map the option values to the values you want to put in `vki`.

```
$("Fletter").change(function() {
    var vki_map = {
        A: 5,
        B: 7,
        ...
    }
    vki = vki_map[$(this).val()];
});
```

But I wonder why you don't just put these values in the `<option>` directly, e.g.

```
<option value="5">A</option>
<option value="7">B</option>
...
```

Then you could do:

```
vki = parseInt($(this).val, 10);
```